# OpenGL issue with calculating reflection/refraction and uniforms

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to calculate the reflection/refraction but with I perform a

```c
gl_FragColor = mix(objectColor, environmentColor, 1.0f);
```

I start getting uniform errors that it can't find my uniform for `lightPosition`. This doesn't make sense as I'm using that uniform for calculating the diffuse lighting and when I remove the mix function to just `gl_FragColor = objectColor;` its fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, if anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `gl_FragColor = mix(objectColor, environmentColor, 1.0f);` is equal to `gl_FragColor = environmentColor;`. So `objectColor` is not used and therefore `lightPosition` is not used either. Try `gl_FragColor = mix(objectColor, environmentColor, 0.5);` for debug reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mix(x, y, a)` can be expressed as `x*(1.0−a) + y*a`.

The last argument of [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) is a constant. Hence the expression can be optimized by the compiler.

> ```c
> gl_FragColor = mix(objectColor, environmentColor, 1.0f);
> ```

is equal to

> ```c
> gl_FragColor = environmentColor;
> ```

So `objectColor` is not used and therefore `lightPosition` is not used either. Hence the uniform `lightPosition` is not an active program resource.

Comment: Addition: This behavior is described [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Active_uniforms).